# Fixed image and content overlaps fixed sidebar as screen resolution/window size decreases

Tags: html, css, formatting

I have a page with the following structure:

```
<body>
<div id="page">
    <div id="header-container">
        <header>
        </header>
    </div>

    <div id="main-container">
        <div id="main" class="site-main">
            <div id="sidebar-container">
                <div id="sidebar">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="content-container">
                <div id="main-banner-container">
                    <div id="main-banner-holder">
                        <img id="main-banner" src="http://dummyimage.com/900x300/000/fff" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="content" class="content" role="main">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer-container">
            <footer>
                <div id="footer-images">
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
</body>
```

And formatted with the following CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: rgb(0,114,187);
    font-family: verdana;
}

#header-container {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    height: 190px;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 66%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    top: 0px;
}

#sidebar-container {
    height:500px;
    width:320px;
    float:right;
}

#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    color: rgb(211,34,52);
    padding: 10px;
    right: 16.5%;
    top:226px;
}

#content-container {
    width: 72%;
}

#main-banner-container {
    max-width: 900px;
}
```

Viewing the page on a widescreen shows the content fine. However, as I reduce the window size, or if I view the site on a lower resolution screen, the fixed image and the text underneath it starts to obscure the sidebar, even though it does scale a little. Furthermore, when the page is scrolling, even though some of the text move to make space for the sidebar, the text below it overlaps when scrolled.

A rough example of the problem can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/4WQzP/

What changes do I need to make?

EDIT: To clarify, I was hoping a plain CSS/HTML based fix. Javascript is an option, though I'm trying to avoid it since I haven't really used it in this site so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for using an adaptive design used two ways)), the first is to use the [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) framework, the second is writing [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: The site is a Wordpress site, so I dont think bootstrap is really an option. I was really looking for a straight CSS/HTML fix. I don't think a relatively small overlap issue warrants a separate set of special case rules? I guess it would work, but surely there's a cleaner solution?

Comment: In the end, I decided to use media queries. Oh well! Thanks anyway!